# Multicol Alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, multicolumn

I have been trying to find a post similar to this that I made and can't find it.  You can see by my document that my numbers of not aligned in each column. I am wondering how I can fix this.

```
\usepackage[margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\subsection*{Derivatives with Product and Quotient Rules}
Find the derivative of each of the functions below.  Be sure to show your work. 
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $y=\big(4x-4\big)\big(\sqrt{x}+2\big)$
                \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=\dfrac{x+4}{x-4}$
                 \vspace{1.5in} 
            \item $y=\dfrac{x^3}{x-1}$
                 \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=11-x^6\cos x$
                 \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=2x^2e^x$
                 \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=x^7\tan x-\sqrt{x}$
                 \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=\Big(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)\Big(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)$
                 \vspace{1.5in}
            \item $y=x^3\cos x-9x$
                \vspace{1.5in}
       \item $\dfrac{x^8+3x+7}{x^2}$
        \vspace{1.5in}
       \item $y=2\sin x\big(e^x\big)$
        \vspace{1.5in}
    \item $y=\dfrac{\tan x}{x}$
        \vspace{1.5in}
    \item $y=\dfrac{\sin x}{10x}+\dfrac{10x}{\sin x}$
        \vspace{1.5in}
        \end{enumerate}
                \vspace{1.5in}
    \end{multicols}
   \end{document}
```

See questions 8,9, and 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`multicol` is not the right tool. There is the `tasks` package, for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=.5in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tasks}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Derivatives with Product and Quotient Rules}
Find the derivative of each of the functions below.  Be sure to show your work.
\begin{tasks}[
  label=\arabic*.,
  label-width=1.5em,
  label-align=right,
  item-indent=2em,
  label-offset=0.5em,
  after-item-skip=\fill
](2)
\task $f(x)=\bigl(4x-4\bigr)\bigl(\sqrt{x}+2\bigr)$

\task $f(x)=\dfrac{x+4}{x-4}$

\task $f(x)=\dfrac{x^3}{x-1}$

\task $f(x)=11-x^6\cos x$

\task $f(x)=2x^2e^x$

\task $f(x)=x^7\tan x-\sqrt{x}$

\task $f(x)=\Bigl(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigr)\Bigl(x-\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigr)$

\task $f(x)=x^3\cos x-9x$

\task $f(x)=\dfrac{x^8+3x+7}{x^2}$

\task $f(x)=2e^x\sin x$

\task $f(x)=\dfrac{\tan x}{x}$

\task $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{10x}+\dfrac{10x}{\sin x}$

\end{tasks}
\vspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option has been used to show the text block margins.

[image]

The numbering is by column and then by row, but that's how people read.

I had to replace all *y*’s by *f*(*x*), sorry if this bothers you, but it *does* bother me.